# How to combine NSData objects from Bluetooth packet

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, nsdata

I have the following bluetooth packet which contains these individual values:

value 1: 0x2710

value 2: 0000

value 3: 0xFFF

value 4: 0xFEE

value 5: 0x426

The complete packet looks like this: 0x2710 0 FFF FEE 426

My question is how can I convert these values/the complete packet into an `NSData` object?

Comment: Do you want to send or receive this data?

Comment: `NSMutableData` and `appendData:`?